# Why is the list printing incorrectly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Im working on a small mini program and im trying to figure out how to print it off as a list like

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
f

1
2
3
4
5
6
6

:)
:/
:*
8)
:/
;)
;)
```

so forth and so on

```
    with open("alphanum.csv", "r") as infile:
        letters = list()
        numbers = list()
        symbol = list()


        for alphanumsym in infile:
            alphanumsym = alphanumsym.rstrip('\n')
            alphanumsym = alphanumsym.split(',')

            letters.append(alphanumsym[0])
            numbers.append(alphanumsym[1])
            symbol.append(aplhanumsym[2]



            print(letters, numbers, symbol)
```

now i got the list to seperate ish and strip but instead of it printing out on individual lines, its printing as a full block onto the output

'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', ':)', ':/', ':*', '8)', ':('

Comment: There is no code that shows printing here

Comment: What does your input data look like?

Comment: a, 1, :)
b, 2, :/
c, 3, :*
d, 4, 8)
e, 5, :(

Comment: does the answer you seek have letters of `['a']` or something else?

Comment: what i want to do specifically is individually print the items on a single line a piece, going with letters fist, numbers second, then symbols last

Comment: Can you update your question so that for a given set of example input data we can see exactly what you want as your output data?

Answer (score 0):

If your input data looks like:

```
"a, 1, :) b, 2, :/ c, 3, :* d, 4, 8) e, 5, :("
```

And the result you seek is:

```
a
1
2
3
4
5
:) b
:/ c
:* d
8) e
:(
```

You can get that via:

```py
data_in = "a, 1, :) b, 2, :/ c, 3, :* d, 4, 8) e, 5, :("

letters = list()
numbers = list()
symbols = list()
candidates = map(str.strip, data_in.split(","))
for candidate in candidates:
    ## are all characers in candidate are letters?
    if all(c in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" for c in candidate.lower()):
        letters.append(candidate)
        continue

    ## are all characers in candidate are digits?
    if all(c in "1234567890" for c in candidate):
        numbers.append(candidate)
        continue

    symbols.append(candidate)

for item in letters + numbers + symbols:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Appreciated this helped a lot!